# How do i use telegram login widget in razor page correctly?

Tags: asp.net, blazor, telegram, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

I need to implement telegram auth in blazor wasm website

i've done it like that since you can't use script tags in razor page normally

script suppress-error="BL9992" async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?22" data-telegram-login="berbraloginbot" data-size="large" data-request-access="write">

and changed application Url to https://127.0.0.1:7051 to set a domain for a bot to make it work on localhost.

[but it seems that it doesnt work because button looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaJst.png)

any ideas weather it has something to do with suppress-error="BL9992" or how is the site hosted or how to do it properly